# Changing the alignment of chapter headings and quotes in quotchap

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, chapters, quotchap

How can I change the alignment of chapter headings and quotes in `quotchap` without modifying the .sty file? More specifically, I would like left-align the chapter headings and right-align the quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by redefining some of `quotchap`'s internal macros. (Note that my solution somewhat increases the vertical space required by the chapter heading.)

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{quotchap}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
  \thispagestyle{plain}%
  \global\@topnum\z@
%   \@printcites% DELETED
  \null\hfill\@printcites\par% NEW
  \@afterindentfalse
  \secdef\@chapter\@schapter
}
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \chapterheadstartvskip%
%   {\size@chapter{\sectfont\raggedleft% DELETED
  {\size@chapter{\sectfont\raggedright% NEW
    {\chapnumfont
      \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
      \if@mainmatter\thechapter%
      \fi\fi
      \par\nobreak}%
%     {\raggedleft\advance\leftmargin10em\interlinepenalty\@M #1\par}}% DELETED
    {\raggedright\advance\leftmargin10em\interlinepenalty\@M #1\par}}% NEW
  \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{savequote}[5cm]
A quote.
\qauthor{The author}
\end{savequote}

\chapter{foo}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your help :)