# Modifying alignment of chapter title in Harvard PhD Thesis LaTeX Template

Tags: alignment, thesis

I am trying to use "PhD Thesis and Dissertation LaTeX Templates for Harvard, Princeton and New York University (NYU)" available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/phd-thesis-and-dissertation-latex-templates-for-harvard-princeton-and-new-york-university-nyu/wkzvtymyxqvv) but there are so many layers and folders and files, which makes it very complicated to navigate for someone like me who's very new to Tex.

When we look at the chapter title and numbering, we see this
[image]

Is it possible to move both the chapter number and chapter title to the left?

I looked into the `style.sty` file under `packages`, in the `Harvard` folder, but I couldn't change this.

Could someone help please?

Comment: To left-align the chapter headings and right-align the quotes see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15047/42803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template loads the `quotchap` package to write citations but at the same time changes the style of the chapter headings (large numbers and over the right margin).

Adding this code before `\begin{document}`

```
%****************************************** add before \begin{document}
\newcommand{\setchapterhead}{\raggedright} % use it to move the chapter headings

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip%
    {\size@chapter{\sectfont\setchapterhead{\chapnumfont%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
                \if@mainmatter\thechapter%
                \fi\fi
                \par\nobreak}%
            {\setchapterhead\advance\leftmargin10em\interlinepenalty\@M #1\par}}
        \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip}}
\makeatother
%*************************************************************
```

will allow to move the header to the left margin using

```
\newcommand{\setchapterhead}{\raggedright}
```

or center it in the text area using

```
\newcommand{\setchapterhead}{\centering}
```

[image: b]

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex 
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% Modify the following line to match your school
% Available options include `Harvard`, `Princeton`, and `NYU`.
\documentclass[School=Harvard]{Dissertate}
\usepackage{showframe} % ONLY to show the margins

%****************************************** add before \begin{document}
\newcommand{\setchapterhead}{\raggedright} % use it to move the chapter headings

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{\chapterheadstartvskip%
    {\size@chapter{\sectfont\setchapterhead{\chapnumfont%
                \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne%
                \if@mainmatter\thechapter%
                \fi\fi
                \par\nobreak}%
            {\setchapterhead\advance\leftmargin10em\interlinepenalty\@M #1\par}}
        \nobreak\chapterheadendvskip}}
\makeatother
%*************************************************************

\begin{document}
    
    % the front matter
        
    % include each chapter...
    \setcounter{chapter}{-1}  % start chapter numbering at 0
    \include{chapters/introduction}
    
    
\end{document}
```

The `\setchapterhead` command is used twice in the chapter header style: first to set the chapter number and then to set the chapter title.
If you want to move them independently, you must define two new commands in their place, such as `\setchapternumber` and `\setchaptertitle` and apply them accordingly.